# Failure with compilation D code

Tags: d

I have multiple issues. First, if I want to compile simple hello world program with GDC, it return me an error: function expected before (), not writeln of type int.

```
module test.main;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
     writeln("Hello world");
}
```

If I use online compiler at compileonline.com. It works fine (interesting ...).
And second problem. If I want to call destructor via destroy(object). It was return error: Error: undefined identifier destroy.

Comment: I don't have GDC, but the code compiles just fine with DMD2 (as does `destroy(object)`).

Comment: I need GDC because I know (and need) GNU toolchain (GDC -> as -> ld).

Comment: Make sure you have the new version, you might have a really old compiler. Note too btw that dmd also uses ld. While it doesn't use as, you can still disassemble its output with objdump or you can link in functions written with as.

Comment: check the version by makign a little D file with this: `pragma(msg, __VERSION__);` and see what it says when you compile it.

Comment: yeah, it's my fault, I have old GDC (D1), but I cannot find newer (compiled...). By the way, what was __ctor() and __dtor() and where they are defined?

Comment: I suggest you edit your original post and remove the (unfair) last statement. Otherwise I will have no other choice but to downvote...

Comment: __ctor and __dtor are just the names of the constructors and destructors. They aren't formally defined anywhere, those are just the names the compiler translates the this() and ~this() functions to and lets you access them later without the keyword. I don't know if there's gdc binaries you can use or not, probably depends on your distro, but the wiki has some info: http://wiki.dlang.org/GDC#Binary_Releases

Answer (score 0):

To your second problem: Use unified function syntax and class the destroy function as a member of the object that you want to destroy. Or better yet, let the garbage collector handle this for you.

Comment: writeln has been in std.stdio for a very long time... I think added around 2007. It wasn't in D1 but that's really old now.

Comment: I don't know why that thing was in the back of my head, but you're right.

Comment: yea, I was wrong. The function exists and should work. I tested it with DMD and it went fine... I had an error like *function writeln does not exist* when I started learning D, and that thought seems to have persisted ^^